# trying to get the index of an element in a vector with classes in C++

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I was making a simple TicTacToe game with SFML but I ran into a weird error when trying to get the index of elements from a vector, and I'm not really sure whats wrong or how to fix it, so I constructed a small example that runs the same error in hopes someone could find whats wrong.

**main.cpp:**

```cpp
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"

using std::vector, std::find, std::distance, std::cout, std::endl;


class exampleClass {
    public:
        exampleClass() {}
        virtual ~exampleClass() {}
};


int getIndex(vector<exampleClass>& vectorToIterate, exampleClass elementToFind) {
    vector<exampleClass>::iterator itr = find(vectorToIterate.begin(), vectorToIterate.end(), elementToFind);
    int index = distance(vectorToIterate.begin(), itr);

    return index;
}


int main() {
    vector<exampleClass> vectorToIterate;
    exampleClass elementToFind;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 5) {
            vectorToIterate.push_back(elementToFind);
            continue;
        }

        exampleClass fillingElement;
        vectorToIterate.push_back(fillingElement);
    }

    cout << getIndex(vectorToIterate, elementToFind) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output/error:**

```
In file included from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Marsel\Desktop\tictactoe\error.cpp:1:
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<exampleClass*, std::vector<exampleClass> >; _Value = const exampleClass]':
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:2069:14:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<exampleClass*, std::vector<exampleClass> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const exampleClass>]'
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:2114:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<exampleClass*, std::vector<exampleClass> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const exampleClass>]'
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algo.h:3884:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<exampleClass*, std::vector<exampleClass> >; _Tp = exampleClass]'
C:\Users\Marsel\Desktop\tictactoe\error.cpp:16:43:   required from here
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\predefined_ops.h:270:24: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'exampleClass' and 'const exampleClass')
  270 |         { return *__it == _M_value; }
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Marsel\Desktop\tictactoe\error.cpp:1:
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1121:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)'
 1121 |     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1121:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Marsel\Desktop\tictactoe\error.cpp:1:
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\predefined_ops.h:270:24: note:   'exampleClass' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'
  270 |         { return *__it == _M_value; }
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Marsel\Desktop\tictactoe\error.cpp:1:
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1129:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)'
 1129 |     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_iterator.h:1129:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ios:40,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Marsel\Desktop\tictactoe\error.cpp:1:
c:\programdata\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\predefined_ops.h:270:24: note:   'exampleClass' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>'
  270 |         { return *__it == _M_value; }
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
[Finished in 3.4s]
```

Comment: `exampleClass` instances have no mechanism for comparison to each other. You need to either provide one, or a predicate comparator that provides it for you (somehow). And in your example they have no actual instance distinction (no members) anyway.

Comment: Your class doesn't have member variables and the element you're looking for is copied to the vector and so is the third argument of `getIndex`, so there's no way of identifying at which index the element is a copy of `elementToFind` and which one is a copy of `findElement`.

Comment: Side note: `#include "iostream"` should be `#include <iostream>`. The quotes tell the preprocessor to search the same folder as the file being compiled. The angle brackets tell the preprocessor to search the include paths. Come compilers search one, then the other, but they are not required to. In other words this code won't necessarily compile, but it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Appearently all I had to do was add something to `exampleClass` that `std::find` can use to differentiate between the other `exampleClass`(s). So I did this and it seems to work.

```cpp
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"

using std::vector, std::find, std::distance, std::cout, std::endl;


class exampleClass {
    public:
        int value;

        exampleClass(int value) {
            this->value = value;
        }
        virtual ~exampleClass() {}
};


constexpr bool operator==(const exampleClass& lhs, const exampleClass& rhs) {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value;
}


int getIndex(vector<exampleClass>& vectorToIterate, exampleClass elementToFind) {
    vector<exampleClass>::iterator itr = find(vectorToIterate.begin(), vectorToIterate.end(), elementToFind);
    int index = distance(vectorToIterate.begin(), itr);

    return index;
}


int main() {
    vector<exampleClass> vectorToIterate;
    exampleClass elementToFind(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 5) {
            vectorToIterate.push_back(elementToFind);
            continue;
        }

        exampleClass fillingElement(i);
        vectorToIterate.push_back(fillingElement);
    }

    cout << getIndex(vectorToIterate, elementToFind) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code looks good.

Comment: Shouldn't the header file be included by insertion operator rather than the double quotation marks?